# How did I get +4 reputation for my suggested edit?

Tags: bug

Today I made an edit on a user's post. Before doing that edit my reputation was '**329**'. After couple of mins, I got **+4** in notification for my suggested edit.!!

> [image]

Of course It added **+2** to my total reputation. How could it happen? Is it a bug?

There seems to be another bug in total reputation, Find the screen-shot below.

> [image]

The total gives me **332** but reputation showing **331** where did I lost my **1** reputation ;). If I consider **+4** as **+2**, the total gives **330** . In this case how did I get **+1** :)

Comment: looks like bug!!! and I think your calculation is wrong 329+4 = 333 so you lost 2 points.

Comment: @Bala - Yes but suggested edit gets +2 reputation right. so If we consider like it's valid

Comment: Looking into this.  Give me a little while.

Comment: have you edited the same post twice!

Comment: Looks like a system wide bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226977/reputation-increases-by-4-instead-of-2